# About equations

Tags: logic

Let  be the signature with a constant $0$, a unary symbol $s$, and a binary symbol $+$. Our favorite example of $\sigma$-algebra is the natural numbers with the usual interpretations of the symbols. Let $\gamma$ be the set of two identities:

\begin{align}0 + y &= y \\
s(x) + y &= s(x + y)\end{align}

These are called the recursion equations for $+$. Prove that $\gamma \not\models x + y = y + x$. That is, the
commutative law of $+$ does not follow from the recursion equations for $+$.

I'm really stuck with this question.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to prove that $\gamma$ *doesn't* entail something, you need to build a *model* of $\gamma$ in which that thing is false. So in this case, we want to build a set $A$ with two operations $\oplus$ and $\mathfrak{s}$ and a special element $\Omega$ (written differently to emphasize that they're weird) such that

- $\Omega\oplus y=y$ for all $y$, and
- $\mathfrak{s}(x)\oplus y=\mathfrak{s}(x\oplus y)$ for all $x$ and $y$; but
- $x\oplus y$ is not necessarily the same as $y\oplus x$.

A useful counterexample here is the *right projection* function: $a\pi_rb=b$. It's not commutative in any structure with more than one element, since $a\pi_rb=b$ but $b\pi_ra=a$ (There's also left projection, of course.) Also, right projection trivially satisfies the first axiom of $\gamma$, regardless of what $\Omega$ is.

So this gives us a first guess as to what our model should be:

- Our underlying set should be something simple, say $\{0, 1\}$ (could be more complicated, but why do that if we don't have to?).
- Our $\oplus$ is just right projection.
- Our $\Omega$ is $0$ (doesn't matter which one we pick).

But we don't know what $\mathfrak{s}$ should be at the moment.

So let's think about it. We'll want $\mathfrak{s}(x)\oplus y=\mathfrak{s}(x\oplus y)$. But we've already decided what $\oplus$ is - it's just right projection! So we can simplify both sides of this equation. Do you see how to do this simplification? Do you see what this suggests $\mathfrak{s}$ should be defined as?

Once you fill in that gap, you'll get a structure which makes $\gamma$ true but in which $\oplus$ isn't commutative.